# PIG and HIVE connectivity to Datastax Cassandra running huge no of maps

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra, hive, datastax-enterprise

I am using DSE3.2.4
I have created three tables which have 10M rows in one and 50k rows in other and other with just 10 rows
When I run a simple PIG or Hive query over these tables it is running same no.of mappers for both the tables.

In Pig by default `pig.splitCombination` is `true` where in it is running only one map
If I set this to false it is now running 513 maps.

In Hive by default it is running 513 maps

I tried in setting the following properties

```
mapred.min.split.size=134217728 in `mapred-site.xml` now running 513 maps for all
```

`set pig.splitCombination=false` in pig shell now running only 1 for all the tables

But no luck

finally I find `mapred.map.tasks    = 513` in `job.xml`

I tried to change this in `mapred-site.xml` but it is not reflecting

please help me in this

Answer (score 1):

The mapper is managed by split size, so don't config it through hadoop settings, try pass &split_size= to your pig url. set "cassandra.input.split.size" for hive

default is 64M

If your Cassandra uses v-node, it creates many splits, so if you data is not big enough, then turn off v-node for hadoop nodes